# How to destroy the previous frame open opening a new frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am building an application in java that has 2 JFrames. 1st frame has a button that upon clicking should open the next JFrame while the previous one should close. I know how to display the next frame but:
**How do I close the previous JFrame automatically when the next JFrame opens ?**

I tried thie following code:

```
addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new GUI();//next frame
                                this.dispose();//compile-time-error
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where you call `this.dispose()`, the object referred by `this` is an instance of `ActionListener`. To invoke the instance of GUI type `GUI.this.dispose()` instead.

Comment: a simple `dispose()` without `this` should also work (assuming the code is inside the "previous JFrame").